# No input from F# printf

Tags: f#

I am going through the "Try F#" tutorial and decided that I wanted to try writing the code in the editor to Visual Studio once I installed the necessary F# plugins.

The code is:

```
    let toHackerTalk (phrase:string) =
        phrase.Replace("t", "7").Replace("o", "0")

    let name:string = "tom"
    printf "%s",toHackerTalk name
```

The code runs on the online editor, but when I try running it on Visual Studio all it does is flash the command prompt asking me to press a key to continue. I realize that this must be a very basic question, I just can't see what the problem could be since it runs perfectly fine in the online editor.

Comment: where is this on the TryF# site? This is surely a *bug* and we should file it - BTW: it will run in your Fsharp-Interactive window too (just like on TryF#) - as Nikon said the last is a tuple where the second part evaluates to what you want to see (maybe you did not notice the first part in the output or ignored it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should do:

```
printf "%s" (toHackerTalk name)
```

see demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ft9O4z

because with F# you dont need to separate function parameters with comma, comma is used for tuples:

```
let d = printf "%s",toHackerTalk name
printfn "%A" d // (<fun:d@6>, "70m")
```

you are creating a tuple with two values `( (printf "%s"), (toHackerTalk name) )`:

```
printf "%s" // a function string -> unit
"70m" // a string
```

you dont get error because you are creating a tuple, who is ignored (maybe you get a warning asking to ignore value)

you cannot do

```
printf "%s" toHackerTalk name
```

because this mean call printf with 3 args:

1. `"%s"` a string
2. `toHackerTalk` a function string -> unit
3. `name` a string

and `printf "%s"` expect only 1 string arg

so you need to do

`printf "%s" (toHackerTalk name)` to execute `toHackerTalk name` and pass result as argument

is the same as

```
let temp = toHackerTalk name // or (toHackerTalk name) parens are optional
printf "%s" temp
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, but `printfn "%s"` is a function `string -> unit` (also the correct spelling is "comma").

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I will continue experimenting with F#, thank you for the great and thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Your `printf` line should look like this:

```
printf "%s" (toHackerTalk name)
```

Otherwise, you are creating a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx) instead of calling `printf`.